# Windows 7 black screen after installing latest patch

Tags: windows-7

Yesterday Windows Update installed the latest 2 patches. After doing the reboot, I got the black screen. System Restore didn't fix it. What can be done?

EDIT: I was able to retrieve the Windows Update log "ReportingEvents.log" and here are the entries that lead to my computer not being able to start up.

```
CB67D8F1-8A81-4DB5-9AD3-57F53DEA2EE9}   2015-02-12 19:34:32:135-0500    1   188 102 {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}  0   0   AutomaticUpdates    Success Content Install Installation Ready: The following updates are downloaded and ready for installation. This computer is currently scheduled to install these updates on ‎Friday, ‎February ‎13, ‎2015 at 3:00 AM:  - Update for Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Tools for Office Runtime (KB3001652) - Security Update for Internet Explorer 11 for Windows 7 for x64-based Systems (KB3034196)
{62A7537A-9449-47E5-A831-EDAFB1E0ABB9}  2015-02-12 19:44:47:974-0500    1   147 101 {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}  0   0   Microsoft Security Essentials ( Success Software Synchronization    Windows Update Client successfully detected 1 updates.
{87133A25-48DF-4A42-BFC2-8D568E0F0448}  2015-02-12 19:49:26:198-0500    1   147 101 {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}  0   0   AutomaticUpdates    Success Software Synchronization    Windows Update Client successfully detected 6 updates.
{C6DB59F8-BB8B-436A-8A01-C316CF4284BB}  2015-02-12 19:50:06:139-0500    1   162 101 {ACE06919-57FF-4FF8-B03B-7D3EF194CB9D}  201 0   Microsoft Security Essentials ( Success Content Download    Download succeeded.
{78580294-B153-47C0-AD73-106B84DD7B0F}  2015-02-12 19:50:38:460-0500    1   183 101 {ACE06919-57FF-4FF8-B03B-7D3EF194CB9D}  201 0   Microsoft Security Essentials ( Success Content Install Installation Successful: Windows successfully installed the following update: Definition Update for Microsoft Security Essentials - KB2310138 (Definition 1.191.4790.0)
{B80A0373-9EDA-4389-8230-99E2FBC01E1D}  2015-02-12 22:43:51:212-0500    1   197 101 {6D8FB942-0A54-47C9-98D3-3C006D5A733E}  204 0   AutomaticUpdates    Success Content Install Installation Successful: Windows successfully installed the following update: Update for Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Tools for Office Runtime (KB3001652)
{18CF67E4-2AAF-481B-8197-481603AF6A70}  2015-02-12 22:44:29:289-0500    1   197 101 {C45174F0-DC54-463C-9CFB-DEC2B12C7A6E}  217 0   AutomaticUpdates    Success Content Install Installation Successful: Windows successfully installed the following update: Security Update for Internet Explorer 11 for Windows 7 for x64-based Systems (KB3034196)
```

The KBs that most likely caused the black screens are:

- KB3034196
- KB3001652

Comment: So you rolled your system back to a previous state from before the update was installed.  What updates were installed exactly?

Comment: I don't know and I can't check.

Comment: It does work in Safe Mode, as I assume that's how you did Restore? If so, can you go to the *Programs and Features* select *View Installed Updates*, sort by date, and remove those installed last? [Not sure if the CPL has that ability in Windows 7]

Comment: IF it works in safe mode then you can answer my question

Comment: I did the restore through the diagnose window that pops up because Windows can't start up.

Comment: I was able to retrieve the Windows Updates log by loading a Linux Live.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked around the issue by installing Linux.